# C++: Adding automatically allocated objects to a std::vector

Tags: c++, object, stl, vector, allocation

I wrote the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class AClass
{
    public:
        int data;

        AClass() 
        { data = -333; cout << "+ Creating default " << data << endl; }

        AClass(const AClass &copy) 
        { data = copy.data; cout << "+ Creating copy of " << data << endl; }

        AClass(int d) 
        { data = d; cout << "+ Creating " << data << endl; }

        ~AClass() 
        { cout << "- Deleting " << data << endl; }

        AClass& operator = (const AClass &a)
        {  data = a.data; cout << "= Calling operator=" << endl; }
};

int main(void)
{
    vector<AClass> v;

    for (int i = 3; i--; )
        v.push_back(AClass(i));

    vector<AClass>::iterator it = v.begin();
    while (it != v.end())
        cout << it->data << endl, it++;

    return 0;
}
```

And the output from the program is:

```
+ Creating 2
+ Creating copy of 2
- Deleting 2
+ Creating 1
+ Creating copy of 1
+ Creating copy of 2
- Deleting 2
- Deleting 1
+ Creating 0
+ Creating copy of 0
+ Creating copy of 2
+ Creating copy of 1
- Deleting 2
- Deleting 1
- Deleting 0
2
1
0
- Deleting 2
- Deleting 1
- Deleting 0
```

Then I changed the class to:

```
class AClass
{
    public:
        int data;

        AClass(int d) 
        { data = d; cout << "+ Creating " << data << endl; }

        ~AClass() 
        { cout << "- Deleting " << data << endl; }
};
```

And the output becomes:

```
+ Creating 2
- Deleting 2
+ Creating 1
- Deleting 2
- Deleting 1
+ Creating 0
- Deleting 2
- Deleting 1
- Deleting 0
2
1
0
- Deleting 2
- Deleting 1
- Deleting 0
```

It appears that vector is making copies of existing objects when new ones are added, but it seems like a lot of unnecessary allocation/deletion is taking place. Why is this? Also, why does the second version work when I haven't provided a copy constructor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> It appears that vector is making copies of existing objects when new ones are added

When you add an element, e.g. with `v.push_back(AClass(i));`, what is done is a temporary `AClass` object is created and passed to `push_back`.  `push_back` must then copy this object into the container.

The other reason that you see copies made is that `std::vector` stores its elements contiguously in an array.  If there is no room left in the underlying array and you try to add another element to the end, the `std::vector` must create a new array, copy the elements from the old array into a new one, and then insert the new element at the end.  If you don't want this to occur, you can call `std::vector::reserve` to reserve sufficient space in the `std::vector` before you start inserting elements, or you can use a different sequence container, like `std::deque`, which does not store its elements contiguously.

> it seems like a lot of unnecessary allocation/deletion is taking place

In a C++ program, objects are frequently created and destroyed.  Note that in your program, `AClass` is very cheap to copy:  its size is probably four or eight bytes, just large enough to hold its `int` data member.

If you have a type that is expensive to copy (e.g., perhaps you have a large tree data structure that has thousands of nodes), then yes, copying may be too expensive.  In that case, you can store smart pointers to dynamically allocated objects in the `std::vector` instead (a `std::vector<shared_ptr<AClass> >`, for example).  If your compiler supports rvalue references and has a move-aware Standard Library implementation, you can make an expensive-to-copy type movable by implementing a move constructor and move assignment operator and using `emplace_back` instead of `push_back`.

> why does the second version work when I haven't provided a copy constructor?

If you don't declare a copy constructor, the compiler provides a default copy constructor for you.

Comment: Thanks! That helps a lot - your answer addressed every part of the question.

Answer (score 5):

Vector uses a regular array of T as its store -- when you create one of these, it has to initialize the space somehow, and the only option is a default constructor.  Later, when you set the value of an index, it copies it onto that space.

In the second version, even if you don't provide a copy constructor, one is generated for you automatically.  If you declare a private one, and then don't implement it, you will see an compiler error (because you have suppressed the generation of the default)

Answer (score 3):

Your objects are copied, because vector is expanding its internal storage. Call `vector::reserve` beforehand to preallocate memory, if you want to avoid the copies. If you don't provide your own copy ctor, compiler will generate one for you (one that copies all members).

Comment: I thought that once you declared any non-default constructor, the compiler expected you to provide all necessary ctors. I guess that was wrong! Thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: @milesleft:  If you declare any constructor for your class, the compiler will not automatically generate the default constructor.  It will, however, automatically generate a copy constructor unless you declare your own copy constructor.

Answer (score 0):

first of all copy cunstructor isusualy generated by c++ itself if you don't provide one, and vector is copying all the data since it's not sure if the variable you gave him has valid value whenever you asked for it, for example you can use some local variable and pass it to the vector, if vector doesn't copy what you gave it, and you return that vector, there will be some memory violations. whever you add some new object to it and it needs a bigger array to store all the object it allocate a new array, and then copy all the existing data into the new array.